# VMWARE Player Kernel-Headers

Tags: arch-linux, vmware-workstation, kernel-module

I downloaded VMware-Player-16.1.2-17966106.x86_64.bundle from VMware website. I followed Arch wiki guide to Install and run because, I use Arch . I downloaded all the necessary packages including linux-header. But I get this error.[image]

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure output of `pacman -Q linux linux-headers` match . If not perform a full system upgrade to match kernel and kernel headers. For that run `pacman -Syu` For more refer https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance . After that reboot your system . This will solve the issue.